# IIS Site won't show Static Content when running as a domain user on Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

looking some advise.

I have a 2019 Windows Server running IIS.

When I build a site (using Windows Authentication) I tell the application pool for that site to run as a domain user.  When I do this the site fails to load any static content (html, css etc) - giving an Internal Server Error (500).

The site in question is a C# .Net application, any of the .aspx files work fine, but the html pages don't.  When I say the .aspx pages work they show the data but not the html static content (i.e. styling)

The site runs as a domain user (a service account) as the application communicates back to a SQL Server database, with that domain user having readwrite permissions - so I can't use any other type of authentication.

When Googling the issue I found the "Impersonate client after authentication", within this I can't see the IIS_IUSRS user listed.  I do see Administrators, Network Service and Local Service.  The option to add here is disabled.

The message states "this setting is not compatible with computers running Windows 2000 Service Pack 1 or earlier".

If I add the domain user that the application pool runs as to the local administrators on the server the web site loads fine, including the html.

I highly doubt this is the correct fix as I'm giving a service account full admin access, can anyone point me in the right direction?  Is there something else I should be doing.

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem permissions issue. Where is your webroot/static files physically located? Is the domain user in any local groups? Does your application pool user have permissions granted to read files on the webroot folder and its parents?

Comment: hey @MisterSmith the web files aren't in the wwwroot folder, but a different folder (on the same drive), the service account (app pool user) has full control of the folder that holds all the files.  If I use procmon I get BAD IMPERSONATION errors.

Comment: Is your domain user in the Users group? Is "wwwroot" in the root of a drive or inside a folder?  Check your Event Viewer logs, and HTTP error logs %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR - any further info?

Comment: Use FRT to learn what module/handler gives you those 500 errors. If you don't start from there, there isn't much to discuss further.

Comment: The MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS I get us "Either a required impersonate level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid".

Comment: @MisterSmith with the domain user added to the "users" group on the server (and removed from the admin group) i get the same module_set_response_error_status.  So at the minute, the only way it works is having the domain user as a local admin.

Comment: Leave them in the users group and try this group policy change: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB56194

Comment: Hey @MisterSmith I’ve passed your suggestion to the team who administrator all our gpo, I’ll update you when they’ve had a chance to look at it.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: For anonymous requests to static files, the IUSR user must have at least read privileges on the resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the static content feature is installed.

Here is the picture:
[image]

Comment: hi, yeah that's all enabled - the site loads fine when the user is a local admin, just fails to display static content when user is not a local admin.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same kind of problem (bootstrap font file triggering error code 500) and finally found a workaround. It looks like IIS is not using the application pool identity to access static content. So in IIS I configured the "fonts" folder to be anonymously accessible and now everything works.
Hope this helps...