# Random 500 internet error on MVC application

Tags: javascript, iis, model-view-controller, http-status-code-500

I have some 500 errors on the website that I deployed. They are very random - from browser inspect, I can see some image or javascript are not loaded. When I refresh the website, they sometimes come back. Or they are all good but when I refresh the site, some image or Js are missing. Since they come back sometime, I will think they are not permission or missing file issue. Could be the application pool not behave consistently? What can be the reason? Can someone advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, can you show me your error messages when image and js are missing?

Comment: This post has the similar issue as I have but it has no final solution.  I am getting the same error in log as "Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. "   I am using window 2019 and local user policy is also disabled. Please advise! 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767943/iis-site-wont-show-static-content-when-running-as-a-domain-user-on-windows-serv/69547393#69547393

Comment: To get the error in detail, you can try to search the Event Viewer and found the Web Event error under Windows Logs -> Application.

Answer (score 0):

If they sometimes work, then it's not a permissions problem, assuming that everything is hosted locally. This sounds more like a memory, network timeout, or hardware failure issue to me.

Comment: Dov, I agree with you. I just don't know how to approve to the network or system group that is memory /network issue since it is behaving so randomly.  Any suggestion? Thanks for your input.

Comment: you need to monitor the server somehow